# using pic in picturebox in code

Tags: c#, picturebox

how can i use a pic i inserted in picturebox into mycodes?thanks

```
public KingPiece(Image image, ChessColor color)
                : base(image, color)
            {


                ValidMoves = new Point(0, -1);    //  Up 1
                ValidMoves = new Point(1, -1);  //  Up 1, Right 1
                ValidMoves = new Point(1, 0);     //  Right 1
                ValidMoves = new Point(0, 1);
                ValidMoves = new Point(-1, 0);
                ValidMoves = new Point(-1, 1);
                ValidMoves = new Point(1, 1);
                ValidMoves = new Point(-1, -1);  //  Left 1, Up 1


            }
```

in this code i want to insert a pic that is in picturebox.plz help me

Comment: What do you mean by use? You should be more detailed and ofc always provide a chunck of code so that we can help you out more efficiently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PictureBox has a property "Image".
In your code you can just do the following:
[Your-PictureBox-Name].Image = Image.FromFile([your filename here]);

of course you can get your image not just from a file but also from a stream, a bitmap or even another picturebox.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx